# Actions on Google dynamic NO_INPUT response via Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google

Is anyone able to get "NO_INPUT" requests from AoG when once they've configured their action.json to route those requests to their server?

I'm receiving "actions.intent.CANCEL" intent requests, but not "actions.intent.NO_INPUT"

My action.json file...

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "thebigbadtest"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "talk to the Sophmora"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "thebigbadtest": {
      "name": "thebigbadtest",
      "url": "https://api.oogum.io/rest/aog/agents/GYuM1j2At8eVLOqh8m1q/apprequests",
      "inDialogIntents": [{
          "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
        }, {
          "name": "actions.intent.NO_INPUT"
        }] 
    }
  },
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am experiencing the same problem. These days, you can also use NO_INPUT_1, NO_INPUT_2 and NO_INPUT_FINAL (https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#system_intents), but that does not work either. I am testing on a Google Nest Hub

Comment: Have you tried with a smart speaker instead of a smart display? I received NO_INPUT when using a smart speaker. I think they don't send NO_INPUT on smart displays, because they expect the screen to maintain a visual indication, or that users will have a visual affordance to resume when ready.